# How to retrieve SQL result column value using column name in Python using MySql data base?

Tags: python, sql

Is there a way to retrieve SQL result column value using column name instead of column index in Python?

```
result = `select name, deptname from employee;`
```

I tried below one:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT name, category FROM animal")
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result_set:
    print "%s, %s" % (row["name"], row["deptname"])
```

Here I got an error like:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Any help will be awesome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly specifying that you need a dictionary cursor. Do that when you call the `connect()` method, set the `cursorclass`:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='user', 
                       passwd='password', 
                       db='db_name', 
                       cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) 
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are getting what you wanted.
You just need to use the row not as a dictionary but as a tuple.
That means that the indices are numbers, not strings.
Try

```
print "%s, %s" % (row[0], row[1])
```

instead

Comment: Yeah, but the OP specifically asks `Is there a way to retrieve SQL result column value using column name instead of column index in Python?`..meaning the OP actually wants dictionary access to the table rows.